# How to test if a file is "complete" (completely written) with Java

Tags: java

Let's say you had an external process writing files to some directory, and you had a separate process periodically trying to read files from this directory. The problem to avoid is reading a file that the other process is currently in the middle of writing out, so it would be incomplete. Currently, the process that reads uses a minimum file age timer check, so it ignores all files unless their last modified date is more than XX seconds old.

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to solve this problem. If the filetype is unknown (could be a number of different formats) is there some reliable way to check the file header for the number of bytes that should be in the file, vs the number of bytes currently in the file to confirm they match?

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas!

Comment: Do you have any control over the process writing files to the directory that you're watching?

Comment: Apart from renaming the file when finished, the approach I take is to make it ok to read the file as it is being written to (think `tail` in Unix)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use an external marker file. The writing process could create a file XYZ.lock before it starts creating file XYZ, and delete XYZ.lock after XYZ is completed. The reader would then easily know that it can consider a file complete only if the corresponding .lock file is not present.

Comment: Hi Michal, how can we check that the "file is locked" through program.

Comment: Here, there are no additional locks on the file - the fact that a file exists or not is what constitutes the lock.

Comment: What if you don't have control on the writer process?

Comment: @Matthieu If you don't know the details of how the writing is executed and don't have control over the writer, you can't guarantee much. If you know some details, for example that the file is opened exactly once for writing, and then closed, you might be able to get information from the OS about open files (as `lsof` does) and check if the file is still open. But such an approach would be a hack: tedious to implement and error-prone.

Comment: Could you please write an example that will illustrate the procedure?

Comment: Yes it is confusing. The question is **how to check completion** and this method proposes to **delete lock after file is completed**.

Answer (score 15):

The way I've done this in the past is that the process writing the file writes to a "temp" file, and then moves the file to the read location when it has finished writing the file.

So the writing process would write to *info.txt.tmp*. When it's finished, it renames the file to *info.txt*.  The reading process then just had to check for the existence of *info.txt* - and it knows that if it exists, it has been written completely.

Alternatively you could have the write process write *info.txt* to a different directory, and then move it to the read directory if you don't like using weird file extensions.

Comment: Thank you, it's a perfect solution. :)

Answer (score 8):

I had no option of using temp markers etc as the files are being uploaded by clients over keypair SFTP. they can be very large in size.

Its quite hacky but I compare file size before and after sleeping a few seconds.

Its obviously not ideal to lock the thread but in our case it is merely running as a background system processes so seems to work fine

```
private boolean isCompletelyWritten(File file) throws InterruptedException{
    Long fileSizeBefore = file.length();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Long fileSizeAfter = file.length();

    System.out.println("comparing file size " + fileSizeBefore + " with " + fileSizeAfter);

    if (fileSizeBefore.equals(fileSizeAfter)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: as mentioned below this might not work on windows. This was used in a Linux environment.

Comment: This code will fail since the file size meta data is written as the first step in Windows. So always the file.length() is same

Comment: In Mac, It works for small files and folders. For large files, instead of length i have used file size and works fine.

Answer (score 6):

One simple solution I've used in the past for this scenario with Windows is to use `boolean File.renameTo(File)`  and attempt to move the original file to a separate staging folder:

```
boolean success = potentiallyIncompleteFile.renameTo(stagingAreaFile);
```

If `success` is `false`, then the `potentiallyIncompleteFile` is still being written to.

Answer (score 3):

This possible to do by using [Apache Commons IO](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) maven library FileUtils.copyFile() method. If you try to copy file and get IOException its means that file is not completely saved.

Example:

```
public static void copyAndDeleteFile(File file, String destinationFile) {

    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File(fileDirectory));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        copyAndDeleteFile(file, fileDirectory, delayThreadPeriod);
    }
```

Or periodically check with some delay size of folder that contains this file:

```
FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(folder);
```

Comment: It is interesting how Commons IO is able to track this. So this would probably answer the original question without complicated copy before.

Comment: The Commons IO implemented the checking by `file.exists() && file.canWrite() == false`, which is not working in Windows. From my observation, `file.canWrite()` returns `true` when file is writing.

Answer (score 2):

Even the number of bytes are equal, the content of the file may be different.

So I think, you have to match the old and the new file byte by byte.

Answer (score 2):

2 options that seems to solve this issue:

1. the best option- writer process notify reading process somehow that
   the writing was finished.
2. write the file to {id}.tmp, than when finish- rename it to {id}.java, and the reading process run only on *.java files. renaming taking much less time and the chance this 2 process work together decrease.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's [Why doesn't OS X lock files like windows does when copying to a Samba share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985034/why-doesnt-os-x-lock-files-like-windows-does-when-copying-to-a-samba-share/9985094#9985094) but that's variation of what you're already doing.

As far as reading arbitrary files and looking for sizes, some files have that information, some do not, but even those that do do not have any common way of representing it. You would need specific information of each format, and manage them each independently.

If you absolutely must act on the file the "instant" it's done, then your writing process would need to send some kind of notification. Otherwise, you're pretty much stuck polling the files, and reading the directory is quite cheap in terms of I/O compared to reading random blocks from random files.

Answer (score 1):

One more method to test that a file is completely written:

```
private void waitUntilIsReadable(File file) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean isReadable = false;
    int loopsNumber = 1;
    while (!isReadable && loopsNumber <= MAX_NUM_OF_WAITING_60) {
        try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            log.trace("InputStream readable. Available: {}. File: '{}'",
                    in.available(), file.getAbsolutePath());
            isReadable = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.trace("InputStream is not readable yet. File: '{}'", file.getAbsolutePath());
            loopsNumber++;
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Unix if you are transferring files using FTP or Winscp:

```
public static void isFileReady(File entry) throws Exception {
        long realFileSize = entry.length();
        long currentFileSize = 0;
        do {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(entry);) {
                currentFileSize = 0;
                while (fis.available() > 0) {
                    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                    int nResult = fis.read(b);
                    currentFileSize += nResult;
                    if (nResult == -1)
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("currentFileSize=" + currentFileSize + ", realFileSize=" + realFileSize);
        } while (currentFileSize != realFileSize);
    }
```