# Getting function to Know the Insertion of file in a folder

Tags: c#

In C# how to know that a file has been inserted into the Folder. I need this in C#.

Comment: If you want to track the fact that the file has been added by some other application, search for FileSystemWatcher. But there are certain complexities there. Eg. read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733816/configuring-filesystemwatcher-such-that-it-raises-created-event-only-when-the-fi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FileSystemWatcher Class to accomplish This task.

Please refer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2157/A-NET-File-System-Watcher

Answer (score 0):

You can determine whether a specified file exists using the Exists method of the File class in the System.IO namespace:

```
bool System.IO.File.Exists(string path)
```

For ex:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // See if this file exists in the SAME DIRECTORY.
    if (File.Exists("TextFile1.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
    }
    // See if this file exists in the C:\ directory. [Note the @]
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\tidy.exe"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
    }
    // See if this file exists in the C:\ directory [Note the '\\' part]
    bool exists = File.Exists("C:\\lost.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(exists);
    }
}
```